# Making Zimbra web mail format replies for not top posting?

Tags: formatting, webmail, zimbra

My company uses Zimbra web mail. I participate in a lot of traditional mailing lists, where top-posting is frowned upon. When I hit reply, I want the message set up for interleaved reply, but instead it's set up for top posting. That is, I'm given a cursor in white space at the top of the page, followed by something like this:

```
-------- Original Message --------
From: Someone Important <blah@example.com>
Sent: Thursday, February 13, 2013 10:10 AM
To: Matthew <mattdm@example.com>
Subject: Re: awesome thing

Blah blah blah blah blah
```

Instead, I want this to start with

```
On Thursday, February 13, 2013 at 10:10 AM, Someone Important wrote:
> Blah blah blah blah blah
```

So I can go through and reply properly. There is an option in Zimbra to prefix with `>`, but nothing I can see to do the formatting right. Is there some sort of plugin or macro that will do this?